# replace column with it relation data in laravel model

Tags: php, database, laravel, eloquent

I need to know is it possible to change the data of field which i have from model to other things ? ?

for example I have `created_by` column and the data inside it is `1`

i have create a relation with User model and everything is fine but i need to replace `created_by` with the name of it user

any suggest please ? ?

this is what i have tried

```
class PostsTranslation extends Model {


    public $appends = [ 'created_by' ];


    public function User() {

        return $this->belongsTo( 'App\User', 'created_by', 'id' )->first();

    }


    public function getCreatedByAttribute() {
        return $this->User()->name;

    }


}
```

the error is this

[image]

I think `$append` replace  created_by value and when the `belongeTo` start it will read it as null

is there is any solution for this or any way to pass `created_by` id with `belongeTo`  ?? ?

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you don't want to access the user's name through the relation?

Comment: no there is no reason for this and if i couldn't find a way I will access it by the relation , but I got a lot of similar situation before (and i couldn't do it )  also for an api it will be more understandable for my team and more clean for the others

Comment: Try this `return $this->belongsTo( 'App\User', 'id' );` and `public function getCreatedByAttribute() {
        return $this->User->name;
    }
`

Comment: but this is what i'm doing now :D  @Maraboc there is no change in the idea

Comment: Not the idea but in the `belongsTo` parameters :p

Comment: no I can't because in your way the foreign_key will not be created_by because i have created_by + updated_by +deleted_by hhhh where you need me to go with those :D

Answer (score 0):

```
getCreatedByAttribute
```

Please, don't. Not only your are messing up with amount of executed sql queries with this approach, but also you are breaking up the way people would understand your code.

```
$translation = PostsTranslation::with('user')->find(1);
$translation->created_by->name;
```

If you want to do this in other way, then apply the getter / setter pattern, like:

```
class PostsTranslation extends Model {
     public function User() {
          return $this->belongsTo( 'App\User', 'created_by', 'id' )->first();
     }
     public function getCreatedBy() {
         return $this->User->name;
     }
}
```

Comment: thank you my friend , for the second one it didn't work and there is no change according to my code , the error is User not found and I did User() the error of the question return back again  , and why it will be messing ? or more query will happen  ? it will be the same in query in my way or in your way :)

Comment: I think it should work, you sure the user with given id really exists?

Comment: yes i'm sure that it exist and if i changed getCreatedBy to something else it's work fine as my example do , but in my case i need to replace it